# Não consigo fixar menu e header do site

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fixar o menu e o header do site, mas não consigo!!
Consegui colocar ele online caso possa dá uma olhada: http://www.projectxna.esy.es/site-teste

Como podem ver, ao usar o scroll do mouse, o menu desce, a logo não desce e nem o header!!

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Não se esquece de sempre fornecer o seu código junto do seu problema para que possamos entender o cenário em que você se encontra.

Comment: Bro, você marcou Bootstrap então coloca na tag parent do menu a classe navbar-fixed-top e coloca seu conteúdo 60px pra baixo com um margin-top

Answer (score 0):

No seu css aplique essas propriedades ao seu header:

```
header {
    position:fixed; //deixa o elemento fixo na pagina
    top:0; //diz qual distância do topo ele ficará fixado, nesse caso, uma distância igual a zero.
    z-index:999; //aplica o nível de profundidade (camadas) do elemento, quanto maior, mais para "cima" na dimensão 'Z' ele vai ficar
}
```

Não se esqueça que após isso, provavelmente você vai precisar colocar uma margem no seu nav, pois ele ficará "por baixo" do menu.